# ImageDataGenerator on a folder

Tags: python, keras

I have a problem with the code in keras document. In the below code, it just loaded 1 image. if I have 10 images in a folder, how am I going to use this code because load_img function just loading 1 image and I want to load my folder which contains 10 images and apply data generation on all images, Any help?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, 
array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img('data/train/cats/cat.0.jpg') # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
save_to_dir='preview', save_prefix='cat', save_format='jpeg'):
i += 1
if i > 20:
break
```

Comment: What is the path of the directory containing images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator and keras will do the thing automatically for you

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(directory)
```

**edit**:
You should have the following folder structure

```
directory/
    class_label_1/
       image1
       image2
       .
       .
    class_label_2/
       .
       .
```

Your parent directory should have one folder for each class and that class folder should have the images belonging to that class. The folder name is picked as the label

Comment: I did what you said, but nothing happened, it just print out "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes".

Comment: Now, It's working "Found 2 images belonging to 1 classes" and I had to add these line to have 20 images per image in a specific folder. Thanks